# factor to numeric conversion - typical solutions aren't working

Tags: r, types, type-conversion

Currently I have a data set where each observation in the column is being recorded as a factor when I am trying to convert it to numeric data. Test.dup is the data set and RightID is the column that will not convert.

As of now I have tried...

```
1.  as.numeric(levels(test.dup$RightID))
2.  as.numeric(as.character(test.dup$RightID))
3.  as.numeric(test.dup$RightID)
4.  Tried assigning RightID as its own vector 
and using method 1 with the vector name instead of test.dup$RightID.
```

However is.factor will always return TRUE and is.numeric will always return FALSE. The above methods seem to be the commonly suggested solutions to my issue. However my issue is not going away.

Example of the RightID column (All right IDs have a duplicate directly next to them):

`RightID
 10012
 10012
 10012
 10012
 10013
 10013
 10014
 10014
 10014
 .. and so on`

It is worth nothing that the original data set I'm working with has approx 300K observations (this is a subset of approx 160K) so I did not scroll through and check to see if there are any non-numeric characters. If there is a quick function to check for the existence of of any non-numeric characters that I don't know of, that would be of great help! The metadata says that this character was a "unique computer-generated ID" so I can't imagine there would be a non-numeric in vector, but you never know.

Comment: Do you get any warnings when you try these methods?

Comment: @G5W yes sorry I will edit that. the code does have it as a lower case.

Comment: @Lamia there were not warning signs when I used these methods.

Comment: I made a data.frame with a factor containing these values. For me `as.numeric(as.character(test.dup$RightID))` worked just fine.

Comment: Can you include a `str()` of your vector? Method 2 should work, and if your vector contains characters, it converts them to NA and throws a warning. If you want to find the elements of your vector that contain something other than numbers, try: `RightID[grepl("[^\\d]",RightID,perl=T)]` .

Comment: I don't know your familiarity with R so I don't mean to be patronizing. But the code you've provided doesn't change the data directly. You need to store the result somewhere for the changes to stick.  If you're just running that code and then trying to use `test.dup$RightID` it won't do anything.

Comment: @Dason thank you. I am a beginner so don't worry. I reran the as.numeric(levels()) function and stored it in test.dup$RightID as you suggested. However, I received a warning message "Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, RightID, value = c(10000, 1e+05, 100001,  : 
  replacement has 166538 rows, data has 178123"

Comment: @DPek I don't know where you got the as.numeric(levels()) code from but that will only return unique values.  Try the second option you give and store it.

Comment: @Dason It worked! Thank you so much!